# Как сделать чтобы из бд sqlite текст в html выводился в исходном форматировании (со всеми абзацами)?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Делаю сайт на Flask. Есть небольшая форма в которой есть тег textarea. Из textarea большой кусок текста добавляется в бд (sqlite). Всё работает нормально, но когда этот текст выводится из бд в html он теряет все абзацы. Например нужно так:

```
     Привет
     Как дела?
```

А выводится так:

```
     Привет Как дела?
```

Просто я новичок. Помогите пожалуйста(

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону тэга `<pre>` https://htmlbook.ru/html/pre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что HTML игнорирует обычные символы переноса строки и пробелы, и для отображения текста с абзацами вам нужно использовать HTML-теги для разрыва строк. Для этого вы можете использовать тег `<p>` для абзацев и тег `<br>` для переносов строки.

Чтобы отобразить текст из базы данных SQLite с сохранением абзацев, вы можете использовать фильтр `Jinja2 safe` в шаблоне Flask.